# XSL-FO keep-together on table-row, weird result

Tags: xsl-fo

I would like to keep certain elements together. As far as I've learned the best way to do it would be with

```
keep-with-next="always"
```

on a table-row.

It does not seem to work the way I thought it would. I built a very basic test:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>70</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>71</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>72</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>73</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

resulting in the following page break:

[image]

Now I would like to keep lines 71 and 72 together.

I tried to put

```
keep-with-next="always"
```

on line 71. I would expect that line 71 gets pushed down to the next page. What actually happens is, that line 70 also gets pushed down. This is unwanted and just rips apart the layout in a different way (another block that is supposed to be kept together is separated).

[image]

**How can I keep line 71 and 72 together while leaving line 70 alone?**

Comment: Which formatter are you using?

Comment: I am assigned to a .NET project - we are using a library called Fonet (https://fonet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I replaced the *screenshot* of your code with actual *text*, so that it is searchable and easier to use (if you put a screenshot because the text was not visible, the correct way is to use a [code block](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)).

Comment: it sounds like there's a page-break instruction in the code for line 70 (or keep-with-previous on line 71)

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is not necessarily *wrong*, as formatters are free to chose page breaks as they see fit, as long as they respect the contraints expressed in the input: in your example, rows #71 and #72 are indeed kept together as requested.

However, you can use a ***break property*** to force a page break between row #70 and row #71:

```
<fo:table-row break-after="page">
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>70</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>71</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

(or use `break-before="page"` on the following row)

Formatters must respect **all *break properties*** and **as many *keep properties* as possible** (section [Keeps and Breaks](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#keepbreak) in the XSL-FO Recommendation), so this should produce the desired output; if it doesn't, the formatter has definitely a bug.

---

An additional observation about something you wrote:

> This is unwanted and just rips apart the layout in a different way (another block that is supposed to be kept together is separated).

If something is really supposed to be kept together, I think it would be better to explicitly set that constraint in the input using keep properties *from the start*, instead of iteratively adding more and more properties until you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for getting into the whole mess... The real issue at hand is that I have done as you suggest - keep together blocks from the start. Imagine that line 70 (which gets pushed down) was a bigger block that is supposed to be kept together.

The big (kept together) block is also pushed down (just like line 70) to the next page (even though it would have enough space).

The same happens with the block before... and so on. The result is a BLANK FIRST PAGE followed by all the pushed down content.

I hope I described it well enough.